# ¿Cómo hacer que un Webview mande las paginas externas al navegador por defecto o la aplicación más adecuada?

Tags: android, webview-android

Tengo una aplicación que hace uso de un `Webview` que carga diferentes paginas web, pero esas paginas tienen enlaces a páginas externas que no quiero que se abran en el webview si no en el navegador por defecto del dispositivo.

He buscado en Internet y encontré el evento `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` de la clase `Webview` que al parecer controla esto, pero no tengo muy claro cuando se inicia ni como funciona exactamente.

Aquí como tengo mi Webview personalizado (modificado, tenia un error en la forma de mover el cursor)

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = MainActivity.getDataBase();
    String[] colums = {Link.LinkEntry.URL};
    Cursor c = db.query(Link.LinkEntry.TABLE_NAME, colums, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String url1 = c.getString(0);
    c.moveToNext();
    String url2 = c.getString(0);
    c.moveToNext();
    String url3 = c.getString(0);
    String urlHost = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
    Log.d("Host de web", urlHost);
    return !(urlHost.equals(Uri.parse(url1).getHost()) || urlHost.equals(Uri.parse(url2).getHost()) || urlHost.equals(Uri.parse(url3).getHost()));

}
```

He continuado probando y el método tal como esta ahora solo abre los enlaces pertenecientes a eses dominios, pero quería que los demás los abriese en el navegador, mi idea era poner un `Intent` en este método, pero no puedo porque la clase no hereda de `Activity`

Problema Solucionado, adjunto el código de la solucion

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
Context actividad;


public MyWebViewClient(Context actividad){
    this.actividad=actividad;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = MainActivity.getDataBase();
    String[] colums = {Link.LinkEntry.URL};
    Cursor c = db.query(Link.LinkEntry.TABLE_NAME, colums, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String url1 = c.getString(0);
    c.moveToNext();
    String url2 = c.getString(0);
    c.moveToNext();
    String url3 = c.getString(0);
    String urlHost = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
    Log.d("Host de web", urlHost);
    if(urlHost.equals(Uri.parse(url1).getHost()) || urlHost.equals(Uri.parse(url2).getHost()) || urlHost.equals(Uri.parse(url3).getHost())){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        actividad.startActivity(browserIntent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La única forma de hacerlo dentro de un `WebView` es similar a lo que tienes, dentro de tu clase que extiende de `WebViewClient` al detectar cierta condición, cargarías tu página a un navegador del dispositivo, tiene que realizarse mediante un [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) :

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   ...
   ...

   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://http://es.stackoverflow.com/"));
   startActivity(browserIntent);

   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: Pero para ejecutar el método .startActivity necesito estar en una clase que herede de Activity

Comment: Buena anotación, para esto puedes enviar en el constructor el contexto de la Activity :)

Comment: Gracias era justo lo que buscaba, funciona a la perfección :)

Comment: Excelente! saludos masterfabela!.